# Architecting FragmentStatePagerAdapter, ViewModel and a Fragment list

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewmodel

Intro (Questions below):
On my application demands, I need to create TabLayout and a ViewPager extending `FragmentStatePAgerAdapter`. The Viewpager consists of a list of one-type fragment, let's call it ListFragment.

Each `Fragment` displays a single `RecyclerView` list.

Now comes the dilemma. What I wish to achieve, is having a `ViewModel` for each `ListFragment`, which contains the `LiveData<ArrayList>` of the `ListFragment` while keep tracking the of list of fragments its self for any changes (the `Fragment` list can be changed (remove/insert/set))

Here is a picture representation of the App:

[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K68am.png)

Note: The ListFragment and Fragment List could be confusing. The meaning is having a `ArrayList<ListFragment>`, where each ListFragment has a `ViewModel` that holds a `LiveData<ArrayList<Object>>`.

Now things become just complicated:

1)How do I create a `ViewModel`for each `ListFragment`, And where do I store those ViewModels?

2)Upon creating a Fragment List (with a non deterministic size), where do I store the List, and how do I listen to changes in it(like, removing a fragment)?

These questions are all Architect-wise. I have clear understanding of how to implement `ViewModel`, `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and so on, but I am rather confused of, like, where to store, create and so on.

There is no assumption of an Architecture yet. It could be some MVVN or MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I'm somewhat confused over what exactly you are trying to achieve, but I'll give it a shot.

I would have only one ViewModel which is created inside the activity that manages all the List fragments. The ViewModel would then have a hashtable used for storing all the `LiveData<ArrayList<Object>>` that it needs. As a key the hash should either use an index or the fragment it belongs to (preferably the latter). When a fragment should be removed you call a remove method which removes the index/fragment from the hashtable.

To use the ViewModel inside the fragment the Activity injects the ViewModel it has created to the Fragment. That way all fragments share the same ViewModel. Be mindful here in what order you execute things.

```
public class ListsViewModel {
    private HashMap<Integer, MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Object>>> hash = new HashMap<>();

    public void setList(int index, ArrayList<Object> newList) {
        if (!hash.containsKey(index)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No such list.");
        }
        MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Object>> mutableLiveData = hash.get(index);
        mutableLiveData.setValue(newList);
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<Object>> getList(int index) {
        if (!hash.containsKey(index)) {
            hash.put(index, new MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Object>>());
        }
        return hash.get(index);
    }

    public void flush(Object key) {
        hash.remove(key);
    }
}

public interface IListFragment {
    public void setViewModel(ListsViewModel listVM, int index);
}

public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements IListFragment {

    private ListsViewModel vm;
    private int key; // might be needed later for cleanup

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Setup fragment

        someButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                vm.setList(aNewListOrOtherChanges);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewModel(ListsViewModel listVM, int index) {
        this.vm = listVM;
        this.key = index;
        vm.getList(index).observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable ArrayList<Object> newList) {
                // Update UI
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tiago. I was wondering- why did you choose a Hashtable instead of a matrix list? I am currently using an matrix (ArrayList<ArrayList<frag>>), and both the hashtable and the matrix array require a key which in our case is index.

Comment: As you say an index as key (which i am also using in this example) would work just as well with a matrix instead. 

The advantage that the hashmap has is if you want to use the fragment as key, or store different things in it with other keys. But that's not necessary in this scenario so either should work. Another advantage is that clearning previous fragments wouldn't mess up the order the key would always point to the correct data. Where as with an array list each entry after the removed one would shift to the left.