# Application architecture: ViewPager2, Fragments and MutableLiveData

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel, android-viewpager2

Good evening,

I am new at Android App development. I have a project where I receive data from multiple sensors which are connected an instrument.

At this time, I can select any sensor and stream its data using AudioTrack. The streaming is from a service and this service is bound to the MainActivity instance. A single sensor data is streamed at the time. This is working as expected.

Now, I want to plot (using MPAndroidChart) the data for each sensor in its own chart. In the activity_main layout, I added a ViewPager2 element, and Fragments are instantiated by the *PagerAdapter::CreateFragment(int position)* method.

My class model is as follow (based on [a ViewPager2 example](https://androidwave.com/viewpager2-with-tablayout-android-example/)):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter
public class ChannelFragment extends Fragment
public class SensorViewModel extends ViewModel
```

I tested the visualisation of the plots in the Fragments using mock data (and a different colour background). The mock data was generated in *ChannelFragment::onCreateView()* method. This also works, though the mock data is the same for all fragments/charts, but different background colour for each fragment.

In a live test, I also proved to myself that I process changing the visible fragment correctly. I associate each fragment to a specific sensor and the streaming data changes as the visible fragment changes. This is done from MainActivity using *ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback onPageSelected(position)*

I am able to set the sensor data to the SensorViewModel and trigger a notification when calling postValue() from SensorViewModel.

The SensorViewModel contains the following declaration

```
private MutableLiveData<float[][]> sensorLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

and is created in MainActivity::onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
            // Create a ViewModel to hold the audio (sensor) data. This view model is used to communicate
            // with the UI, graphically display the audio data for example
            sensorViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SensorViewModel.class);
```

The code for the observer is defined as a ChannelFragment method and listed as

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        sensorViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SensorViewModel.class);
        sensorViewModel.getSampleData().observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<float[][]>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable float[][] sampleData)
            {
                // Update the sample data graphical representation
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("ChannelFragment; onChanged() sampleData length : %d, size: %d",
                        sampleData.length, sampleData[0].length));
                addEntry(sampleData);
            }
        });
```

And the log statement reports

```
ChannelFragment: ChannelFragment; onChanged() sampleData length : 8, size: 170
```

I am stuck as to update the correct chart (correct ChannelFragment) with its corresponding sensor data.

How to a plot sampleData[0][] in Fragment at position 0, sampleData[1](https://androidwave.com/viewpager2-with-tablayout-android-example/) in Fragment at position 1, and so forth?
Calls to *ChannelFragment.getId()* always returns 0, though I am able to access other attributes such as title when different fragments become visible.

I also modified the SensorVIewModel as suggested by [Tiago Redaelli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817238/architecting-fragmentstatepageradapter-viewmodel-and-a-fragment-list). The new declaration:

```
private HashMap<Integer, MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Float>>> sensorLiveData = new HashMap<>();
```

where the key identifies the sensor/fragment the MutableLiveData belongs to. However, the example does not explain how to set (inject?) the ViewModel (and MutableLiveData value) to the ChannelFragment. In the example, the method *setViewModel()* is implemented but call is not shown.

Using this new ViewModel definition, how do I associate each HashMap values with their corresponding Fragment (who is calling *setViewModel()* ? What I am missing?

Thanks in advance
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update. I was trying to create a complicated solution to my issue, including looking at ViewModel factory for example.
In my solution, I simply call *setViewModel()* (mentioned above) using the position/index value passed as argument when creating an instance of ChannelFragment.

This appears to be working.